# CLR: Multi Param Aggregate, Argument not in Final Output?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, clr

Why is my delimiter not appearing in the final output?  It's initialized to be a comma, but I only get ~5 white spaces between each attribute using:

```
  SELECT [article_id]
         , dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(0, t.tag_name, ',') AS col
    FROM [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[ARTICLE_TAG_XREF] atx
    JOIN [AdventureWorks].[dbo].[TAGS] t ON t.tag_id = atx.tag_id
GROUP BY article_id
```

The bit for DISTINCT works fine, but it operates within the Accumulate scope...

Output:

```
article_id  |  col
-------------------------------------------------
1           |  a         a         b         c
```

Update: The excess space between values is because the column as defined as NCHAR(10), so 10 characters would appear in the output.  Silly mistake on my part...

### Solution

---

With Martin Smith's help about working with the `Write(BinaryWriter w)` method, this update works for me:

```
public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
{
    w.Write(list.Count);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (i < list.Count - 1)
        {
            w.Write(list[i].ToString() + delimiter);
        }
        else 
        {
            w.Write(list[i].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

### The Question:

---

Why does the above solve my problem?  And why wouldn't it let me use more than one `w.write` call inside the FOR loop?

### C# Code:

---

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined, MaxByteSize = 8000)]
public struct GROUP_CONCAT : IBinarySerialize
{
    ArrayList list;
    string delimiter;

    public void Init()
    {
        list = new ArrayList();
        delimiter = ",";
    }

    public void Accumulate(SqlBoolean isDistinct, SqlString Value, SqlString separator)
    {
        delimiter = (separator.IsNull) ? "," : separator.Value ;

        if (!Value.IsNull)
        {
            if (isDistinct)
            {
                if (!list.Contains(Value.Value))
                {
                    list.Add(Value.Value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(Value.Value);
            }            
        }
    }

    public void Merge(GROUP_CONCAT Group)
    {
        list.AddRange(Group.list);
    }

    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        string[] strings = new string[list.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            strings[i] = list[i].ToString();
        }

        return new SqlString(string.Join(delimiter, strings));
    }

    #region IBinarySerialize Members

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        int itemCount = r.ReadInt32();
        list = new ArrayList(itemCount);

        for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
        {
            this.list.Add(r.ReadString());
        }
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(list.Count);
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            w.Write(s);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: It's more than a year since I tried a CLR function but are you sure your Write method is correct? Comparing with here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055.aspx

Comment: @Martin Smith: That's my first thought, but it works if the terminate method returns `return new SqlString(string.Join(",", strings));` so my belief is it's an issue with the variable value & scope.

Comment: I only have SQL 2005 to test against so things might be completely different 
(it only takes one parameter for a start so I needed to alter some things) but 
I found that the delimiter appeared to be ignored and when I changed the code in the 
write method to `w.Write(s); w.Write("*");` stars appeared in the output.

Comment: @Martin: Yeah, 2008+ supports multiple parameter aggregates - 2005 didn't.  The Express editions support CLR, if you find yourself inclined.  The 2008 and 2008R2 use the same CLR version too - 2.0 (.NET 3.5).

Comment: Yes what I meant though is that the Write method doesn't appear to be inserting commas anywhere. The test with the stars shows that the Write method does affect what is output.

Comment: @Martin Smith: Confirmed, if I add the `w.write(delimiter)` I see it in the output.

Comment: Bueller?... Bueller?... Bueller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you do not serialize delimiter. Add:

```
w.Write(delimiter)
```

as a first line in your Write method and

```
delimiter = r.ReadString();
```

as a first line in your Read method.

Regarding your questions to suggested work-around:

> Why does the above solve my problem?

It does not. It merely worked with your test scenario.

> And why wouldn't it let me use more than one w.write call inside the FOR loop?

Write method needs to be compatible with Read method. If you write two strings and read only one then it is not going to work. The idea here is that your object may be removed from the memory and then loaded. This is what Write and Read are supposed to do. In your case - this indeed was happening and you were not able to keep the object value.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @agsamek is correct but not complete. The query processor may instantiate multiple aggregators, e.g. for parallel computations, and the one that will eventually hold all data after successive calls of `Merge()` may be assigned an empty recordset, i.e. its `Accumulate()` method may be never called:

```cs
var concat1 = new GROUP_CONCAT();
concat1.Init();
results = getPartialResults(1); // no records returned
foreach (var result in results)
    concat1.Accumulate(result[0], delimiter); // never called
...
var concat2 = new GROUP_CONCAT();
concat2.Init();
results = getPartialResults(2);
foreach (var result in results)
    concat2.Accumulate(result[0], delimiter);
...
concat1.Merge(concat2);
...
result = concat1.Terminate();
```

In this scenario, `concat1`'s private field `delimiter` used in `Terminate()` remains what it is by default in `Init()` but not what you pass in SQL. Luckily or not, your test SQL uses the same delimiter value as in `Init()`, so you can't reveal the difference.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if it has been fixed in later versions (I stumbled on it in SQL Server 2008 R2). My workaround was to make use of the other group that is passed in `Merge()`:

```cs
public void Merge(GROUP_CONCAT Group)
{
    if (Group.list.Count != 0) // Group's Accumulate() has been called at least once
    {

        if (list.Count == 0) // this Accumulate() has not been called
            delimiter = Group.delimiter;

        list.AddRange(Group.list);
    }
}
```

P.S. I would use `StringBuilder` instead of `ArrayList`.