# Can a sql server aggregate udf be passed in multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, aggregate, user-defined-functions

I am trying to write an aggregate udf for using Sql Server 2008 and C# 3.5 that implodes an aggregation of data.  The kind of syntax I am looking for is:

```
SELECT [dbo].[Implode]([Id], ',') FROM [dbo].[Table] GROUP BY [ForeignID]
```

where the second parameter is the delimiter for the aggregate function.  And example return value would be something like:

```
1,4,56
```

Is there a way to have multiple parameters in an aggregate udf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL 2008 Yes. For an example of one very similar to what you are doing I think see the post here [CLR: Multi Param Aggregate, Argument not in Final Output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940183/clr-multi-param-aggregate-argument-not-in-final-output)

Comment: +1, you should have actually "answered" the linked question, you can't up-vote a comment!